# Inserting dynamics 365 records into SQL Server database using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I am currently working on a project to insert a list of records from a dynamics 365 website into to a SQL Server database. However when I call the class file no insert is currently made into the database.

Can someone assist me? I have placed an ellipsis at the where the code which pulls the data from crm would be as that code works fine and so what you're reading isn't as long. Let me know if it is needed.

```
public class ProgramPVT
{
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ...
                int count = 0;
                int n = count;

                foreach (var item in performancevt)
                {
                    performancevt.Add(item);
                }

                var totalnumber = performancevt.Count;
                var t = totalnumber;
                var accountmanager = new string[t];
                var monthlytarget = new string[t];
                var forecast_ = new string[t];
                var actual_  = new string[t];
                var managedservices = new string[t];
                var pvtpercentage_ = new string[t];
                var mspercentage_ = new string[t];

                SqlConnection crmdbconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source =*****;Initial Catalog=****;User Id = ******;Password = ******;");
                crmdbconnection.Open();

                foreach (var performanceitem in performancevt)
                {
                    accountmanager[n] = performanceitem.accountmanager.ToString();
                    monthlytarget[n] = performanceitem.monthlytarget.ToString();
                    forecast_[n] = performanceitem.accountmanager.ToString();
                    actual_[n] = performanceitem.accountmanager.ToString();
                    managedservices[n] = performanceitem.monthlytarget.ToString();
                    pvtpercentage_[n] = performanceitem.accountmanager.ToString();
                    mspercentage_[n] = performanceitem.accountmanager.ToString();

                    var i = 0;

                    do
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string cmdtext = "INSERT INTO PerformanceVTarget (Account_Manager, Month_Target, Forecast, Achieved, Total_Percentage, MS_Percentage) VALUES (@Account_Manager, @Month_Target, @Forecast, @Achieved, @Total_Percentage, @MS_Percentage)";
                            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtext, crmdbconnection))
                            {
                                {
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Manager", accountmanager[n]);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month_Target", accountmanager[n]);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forecast", accountmanager[n]);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achieved", accountmanager[n]);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Percentage", accountmanager[n]);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Manager", accountmanager[n]);
                                }

                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception fx)
                        {
                            Console.Write(fx);
                            Console.WriteLine("Line with ID:", n, " not inserted");
                            Console.WriteLine("Error - Press enter to Continue");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                        i++;
                    } while (i < t);
                }

                n = n + 1;                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Table PerformanceVTarget**

```
[ID] pk, int ,not null
[Report_ID] int, null
[Account_Manager] varchar(50) not null
[Month_Target] varchar(50) not null
[Forecast] varchar(50) not null
[Achieved] varchar(50) not null
[Total_Percentage] varchar(50) not null
[MS_Percentage] varchar(50) not null
[Team] varchar(50) null
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when running you code? Can you confirm that the INSERT statement works when you try it in SSMS? I strongly suspect you are trying to insert string values into columns with other data types (`Month_Target`, `Forecast`, `Achieved` and `Total_Percentage` sound like decimal or other numerical types).

Comment: @Filburt No i get no exceptions. I've put the table design above for you. Could it be that i'm not calling it properly? I'm currently just trying to call it using a view.

Comment: If data type and length do match it shouldn't matter INSERTing into a view. One more thing is that you seem to set every column value to `accountmanager[n]` which doesn't look like you intend to do creating `monthlytarget[n]` just above. Also your foreach at the top seems strange - do you really need to duplicate every item?

Answer (score 1):

Your code execution will never come out of this loop.

```
foreach (var item in performancevt)
{
    performancevt.Add(item);
}
```

This is a deadlock or you should get an error.

Also you are not passing any value to [MS_Percentage] & Id (primary key field), both are non-null columns.